# Rabbitmq(AMQP) to s3 connector

Tags: amazon-s3, amqp

Is there any reliable connector available for RabbitMQ to S3 (read data from RabbitMQ queues and send to S3 Bucket)?

I am looking something like https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html

I found few like http://michaldul.com/aws/flume/ and https://github.com/AckeeDevOps/rabbitmq-backup-to-s3

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most reliable solution is [Amazon Kinesis Data Frirehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/). There is a nice article describing such case on [AWS blogs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/streaming-real-time-data-into-an-s3-data-lake-at-meetme/).

Comment: any reason why we cannot use boto3 to dump data directly to s3?